# Refer to multiple records of an object in a formula

Tags: formula, salesforce1-app, formula-field

I am trying to create a formula field in salesforce.com that refers to a field value in two different records that are one above the other in a table. For example,

```
ID    |    TEST    |   
123   |    A       |
456   |    B       |
789   |    A       |
```

The formula should begin like this for each record -- "if TEST of ID 123 = TEST of ID 456"

What would the syntax be for this? Thank you.

Comment: How are all of the fields related/what does your schema look like? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to compare a record's "TEST" value with the record above it, and if it is true, I want it to output "TRUE" in a new column.

I am new to creating formula fields and am unsure of the syntax that I should use.

Comment: How are you going to use that formula? Should it be real field? Something to be used in validation rules (VLOOKUP function might be useful) or maybe something to be used in only in reports (I'm thinking about stuff like PARENTGROUPVAL)?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this using a simple formula (there is no way of referencing a sibling record - your concept of "above in a table" is not well defined in Salesforce).

To do this would require some trigger code that checks against another record where you need to define what the previous record is (an auto number field could be used for example).